# Ehy JShint waring will not go away, {"esversion": 6} is not working properly in the .jshintrc

Tags: javascript, jshint

```
import React from 'react';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk];
```

[image]

it keeps showing `Unexpected ES6 feature. (es6)jslint(es6)` when import and const. I have create a `.jshintrc` file and includes `{"esversion": 6}` not sure why warning is still here.

Also, it keeps showing this `Extra semicolon. (semi)standard(semi`), I have added semi:[2,"always"] not sure why it is still showing the error.

this is my eslintrc.json, not sure if anything is related.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true 
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 6 // or 7,8,9
    },
    "extends": ["standard"],
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "rules": {
        "semi": [2, "always"],
        "indent": "off", 
    }
}
```